# Having issues with sys.argv()

Tags: python-3.x, argv

I'm new to python programming and trying to implement a code using argv(). Please find the below code for your reference. I want to apply filter where Offer_ID = 'O456' with the help of argv().

Code:

```
-----
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import sys

data = pd.DataFrame({'Offer_ID':["O123","O456","O789"],
        'Offer_Name':["Prem New Ste","Prem Exit STE","Online Acquisiton Offer"],
        'Rule_List':["R1,R2,R4","R6,R2,R3","R10,R11,R12"]})

data.loc[data[sys.argv[1]] == sys.argv[2]]  # The problem is here

print(data)
```

With this statement I'm getting the output -> "print(data.loc[data['Offer_ID'] =='O456'])"
but I want to accomplish it as shown here "data.loc[data[sys.argv[1]] == sys.argv[2]]" .

Below is the command line argument which I'm using.

python argv_demo2.py Offer_ID O456

Kindly assist me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to what the issue is, but is this what you're trying to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import sys

data = pd.DataFrame({'Offer_ID':["O123","O456","O789"],
        'Offer_Name':["Prem New Ste","Prem Exit STE","Online Acquisiton Offer"],
        'Rule_List':["R1,R2,R4","R6,R2,R3","R10,R11,R12"]})

select = data.loc[data[sys.argv[1]] == sys.argv[2]]  # The problem is here

print(select)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. This is exactly what I wanted. Can you please explain me what the issue was?

Comment: Offer_ID     Offer_Name        Rule_List
O456         Prem Exit STE      R6,R2,R3

This is the expected output, but I want to store the value "O456" in a variable. How can we accomplish it?

Comment: In your original code you weren't doing anything with the data. .loc looks up a row in the dataframe but you need to then save it if you want to keep it for later. select = is essentially saving the output into a variable. O456 is already saved in the argv[1] variable. Can you mark my answer as the solution if I've resolved your issue, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Appreciate it!